# posting file "multipart/form-data" through php

Tags: php, api, post

Im trying to use imageshshack api in php

in the following way:

```
<?php
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}

    $fileName = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['picture']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['picture']['type'];
    $fo = @fopen($tmpName, "r");
    $imgposted = @fread($fo, filesize($tmpName));
    $imgposted = addslashes($imgposted);

    $data = 'fileupload='.$imgposted.'&rembar=1&key=******';
    echo do_post_request('http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php',$data);

?>
```

but the data is being posted normally, I wanted to be posted like if I had a form with this attribute:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
do_post_request(
    'http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php',
    $data,
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data')
);
```

Comment: @racetrack:

thanks, but this error appears:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Problem with http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php, ' in /var/www/html/test/imageshack/rec.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/test/imageshack/rec.php(31): do_post_request('http://www.imag...', 'fileupload=?PNG...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/test/imageshack/rec.php on line 14

Comment: @el7r Updated the answer, try the new one (replacing the array, with string).

Comment: @racetrack:
it returned as it was before,
imageshack says
Sorry, but we've detected that unexpected data is received. Required parameter 'fileupload' is missing or your post is not multipart/form-data

Comment: @racetrack no, I tried a simple html form and it worked correctly and the photo has been uploaded , but I need to do it through html and get the response

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it as a header:

```
$optional_headers = array(
  'Content-Type'=>'multipart/form-data'
);
```

When calling the function:

```
do_post_request('http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php', array(
   'Content-Type'=>'multipart/form-data'
));
```

**EDIT:** I think you also have to `url_encode` rather than doing `addslashes`.

Comment: I tried urlencode, still its not sent as 'multipart/form-data'